# Spring XML context:property-placeholder to Java Spring Boot configs

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm moving my old Spring XML configuration to Java configs at Spring Boot project.

I have a following config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/patient-api.application.properties" order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" order="2" />
```

How to translate this to the appropriate Java config ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/conf/patient-api.application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig{

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer(){
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is fails with a following exception: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Development\3rdparty\apache-tomcat-8.0.38\conf\patient-api.application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: I have added `configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);` but it also doesn't help because looks like `@PropertySource` invokes before `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties(
                    "spring.config.name:patient-api.application,application",
                    "spring.config.location:classpath:/,file:${catalina.home}/conf/")
            .build().run(args);
}

}
```